# How could I replace repeated complex strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, text, replace

For example, the input would be:

`@[facts.::ip](facts.::ip) = "127.0.0.1" AND @[facts.::os](facts.::os) = "ubuntu"`

I would like to transform that into:

`facts.::ip = "127.0.0.1" AND facts.::os = "ubuntu"`

Thanks in advance!

I have tried to check for regex, but I do not have experience with it

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: The online tool [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/sFNvhj/1) can help you find a solution that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below regular expression method achieves required string transformation.

```js
let from = '@[facts.::ip](facts.::ip) = "127.0.0.1" AND @[facts.::os](facts.::os) = "ubuntu"';
let to = from.replace(/(@\[([^\]\)]+)\]\(\2\))/g, "$2");
console.log(to);
```

Comment: What an elegant answer,can you tell me what is `2` represents for in your regex expression

Comment: @lucumt https://regex101.com/r/TgIttI/1